# no kernel in grub

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, kernel

hi linux professionals =O

I had ubuntu 12.04 3.5.0-23-generic dual boot with win7 .but there was a problem to use ati/radeon fglrx on my system so i decided to downgrade kernel (because that driver working with kernel <= 3.4 ) .

I installed linux-image.3.2.0-23-generic and linux-image.3.2.0-24-generic on my system , and i used sudo update-grub to add those kernels to grub boot loader ,and output showed all kernels added to boot loader.

after restart there was just 3.5.0-23 on boot loader so i thought if i uninstall 3.5.0-23 grub can load other kernels ( Im taking shame =[ ) .I uninstalled linux-image-3.5.0.23generic via synaptic and after restart there is just these options on grub boot loader :

memtest

win7

I used live usb to get this informations :

**/etc/default/grub** :

```
> # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
> # /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
> # For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
> #   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
> 
> GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
> #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
> 
> # Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
> # This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
> # the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
> #GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
> 
> # Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
> #GRUB_TERMINAL=console
> 
> # The resolution used on graphical terminal
> # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
> # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
> #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
> 
> # Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
> #GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
> 
> # Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
> #GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
> 
> # Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
> #GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

**there is nothing in /boot** .

1-are those kernles(3.2.0.23 and 3.20.24 ) exists in my system ?

2_if they are in my system how can i add them to grub and use them ?

3-is there a way to get 3.5.0.23 kernel back ?

I read similar threads before but I dont want to re-install ubuntu .
please help me. :'(

**EDIT 1:**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ dpkg -l linux-image*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
un  linux-image    <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-3. <none>         (no description available)
iF  linux-image-3. 3.2.0-23.36    Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 b
ii  linux-image-3. 3.5.0-23.35~pr Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 b
ii  linux-image-ge 3.5.0.23.30    Generic Linux kernel image
```

**EDIT 2** :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -al /boot
total 53021
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       4096 Jul 19 15:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 Jul 19 15:41 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     795572 Apr 11  2012 abi-3.2.0-23-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     856743 Jan 25 21:07 abi-3.5.0-23-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     147316 Apr 11  2012 config-3.2.0-23-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     154436 Jan 25 21:07 config-3.5.0-23-generic
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       4096 Jun 24 17:25 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   20358320 Jul 19 15:41 initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   21986987 Jul 19 15:39 initrd.img-3.5.0-23-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     176764 Nov 27  2011 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     178944 Nov 27  2011 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root   root    2252691 Apr 11  2012 System.map-3.2.0-23-generic
-rw------- 1 root   root    2421090 Jan 25 21:07 System.map-3.5.0-23-generic
-rw------- 1 root   root    4864480 Apr 11  2012 vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
```

**EDIT 3** :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:41:14 UTC 2012 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
:
ubuntu@ubuntu:$ sudo dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
linux-headers-3.5.0-23
linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic
linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic
:
ubuntu@ubuntu:$ uname -sr
Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
```

Comment: "there is nothing in /boot " Then you probably don't have a kernel installed. Please provide the output of `dpkg -l linux-image*` run in a terminal in your question (edit it).

Comment: Well, a kernel *is* installed, but you don't have files in `/boot` you say? One of the statements must be untrue. Please provide the output of `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: thanks gertvdijk for reply ,Is kernel in live usb same by system kernel ?Im using the command s that you want by live usb are the resault is same for linux partition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply repair your grub and boot loader by

```
$ grub-install -v ( check GRUB version and GRUB file:- /boot/grub/grub.cfg )

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
$ boot-repair
```

and reboot ubuntu.

Comment: hi , there is nothing in /boot in installed file system ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/9e5ae4eb-3013-43c9-a790-a9cdd85f786d/boot$.and there is no grub.cfg in /boot/grub in live usb also.